# Is there a way to simplify this code comparing two Points with fields x and y for equality?

Tags: java, instance, equality, simplify

Is there a way to simplify the following code which aims to compare two Points with fields x and y for equality?

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Point) {
            Point c = (Point) o;
            if (!(c.x == this.x && c.y == this.y)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified to:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Point)) {
        return false;
    }
    Point c = (Point) o;
    return x == c.x && y == c.y;
}
```

---

### Explanation

It is shorter and often clearer to replace an if/then boolean conditional that returns `true`/`false` in the condition with the results (or negated results) of the boolean itself.

For instance:

```java
if (someBooleanCondition()) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

can be simplified to

```java
return someBooleanCondition();
```

Applying this to your example:

```java
if (!(c.x == this.x && c.y == this.y)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

becomes:

```java
return c.x == this.x && c.y == this.y;
```

I've put the `instanceof` check first, since I feel short-circuit returning the exceptional case leads to easier to read code, though that is subjective.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is the simplest

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || o.getClass() == getClass()) return false;
    return x == ((Point) o).x && y == ((Point) o).y;
}
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: The current version has a bug where it returns false if both objects have the same class; it looks like `==` should have been `!=`.  Additionally, this version has different behavior than the question's equals method, as it does not treat a subclass instance of `Point` representing the same (x, y) coordinate as being equal to a direct instance of `Point`.